# Android firebase dynamic link doesn't open app

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I'm having trouble intercepting a dynamic link with my app. What I've done:

1) Created a project in Firebase console

2) Set up SHA-1 and SHA-256

3) Set up package name

4) Whitelisted the URL

5) Created a dynamic link and enabled linking to the android app

6) Created an activity with proper intent filter

7) Tested the activity with AppLink Assistant - all ok, intercepting works fine

Yet, when I click on the link I end up landing on the `Dynamic Link Not Found` page. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you figured out the solution? My guess would be that there's something wrong with the whitelisted URLs.

Comment: In my case, I was getting a `Dynamic Link Not Found` page when trying to perform Facebook authentication. The solution was to whitelist `^https://my-app\.firebaseapp\.com/.*$`